# Windows Performance Analyzer - result after freeze in 2 minutes

Tags: windows, performance, logging, event-viewer

My machine crashed for about 2 minutes at around 15:10 24.10.2017. Looking at the graph explorer it looks like Computation, CPU usage and DPC/ISR stopped also, which makes it difficult to diagnose. Also the time on the x-axis is in miliseconds instead of local time which makes it more difficult to relate events to when I experienced the crash. Im running windows 10 (64 bit)

Any ideas what I can do to get closer to the problem next time the pc crashes?

[image: analyser of crash]

Update: I got Intel Core i5-6200 CPU @2.30GHz 2.40 GHz CPU, and caps lock doesnt work when the computer freezes. Its a thinkpad T560

Update2: The Windows Memory Diagnostic tested the computer's memory and detected no errors. But I found some other error in the windows log > SystemDistributedCOM error - with message: "The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID ..."

Comment: press CAPS Lock key during freeze and look at the CAPS Lock status LED on your keyboard. if the light toggles, the freeze is software based, if no light toggle happened the PC freezes because of HW issue.

Comment: Do you have a Skylake/Kabylake cpu that is missing the micro code update?

Comment: I got Intel Core i5-6200 CPU @2.30GHz 2.40 GHz

Comment: any update? what happens when you press CAPS LOCK during freeze?

Comment: caps lock doesnt work when the computer freezes. So I guess its a hardware issue.

Comment: What is the best way to debug a hardware fault?

Comment: use memtest86+ not the normal windows test tool

Comment: Ive run extended memory test from lenovo bios, and test of cpu, motherboard, disk and PCI interface. There was no errors.

Comment: disconnect all hardware, maybe an USB device /dongle causes the freeze

Comment: Ive disconnnected all dongles and the t560 still freezes.

Comment: try BIOS update. also contact Lenovo for support